# How to change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, date

My date is:

> 01/14/2018

I want to change it like:

> 14-01-2018 or 2018-01-14

Comment: You can use `strftime` method.

Comment: `01/14/2018` – is that a string? If so, where does it come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two steps:

- You need to convert your string into `Date` object. For that, use [`Date#strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).
- You can use [`Date#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) to convert the `Date` object into preferred format.

See implementation below:

```
str = '01/14/2018'

date = Date.strptime(str, '%m/%d/%Y')
 => #<Date: 2018-01-14 ((2458133j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
 => "14-01-2018"

date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 => "2018-01-14"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a nuts-and-bolts string manipulation problem. One could convert the strings to date objects then convert those objects back into strings with a given format, but it seems more straightforward to simply use string methods, as I've done below.

We are given the date string

```
str = "01/14/2018"
```

and will use

```
str_fmt = "%s-%s-%s"
```

as a format string.

The simplest way would be to extract the parts of interest of the string using the *slice* method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
str_fmt % [str[3,2], str[0,2], str[6,4]]
  #=> "14-01-2018"
str_fmt % [str[6,4], str[0,2], str[3,2]]
  #=> "2018-01-14"
```

Alternatively, one could use a regular expression with capture groups for the month, day and year.

```
r = /
    \A       # match the beginning of the string
    (\d{2})  # match two digits in capture group 1
    \/       # match a forward slash
    (\d{2})  # match two digits in capture group 2
    \/       # match a forward slash
    (\d{4})  # match two digits in capture group 3
    \z       # match the end of the string
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

str =~ r
str_fmt % [$2, $1, $3]
  #=> "14-01-2018"
str_fmt % [$3, $1, $2]
  #=> "2018-01-14"
```

If named capture groups are to be used we would write the following.

```
m = str.match /\A(?<mon>\d{2})\/(?<day>\d{2})\/(?<yr>\d{4})\z/
str_fmt % [m[:day], m[:mon], m[:yr]]
  #=> "14-01-2018"
str_fmt % [m[:yr], m[:mon], m[:day]]
  #=> "2018-01-14"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'01/14/18'.split('/').rotate(-1).reverse.join('-')
```